# Copy and paste raw text from a FILTER formula

Tags: google-sheets

I need help to figure out something. I have a Filter formula to search if an item is available in my google sheets, it returns the correct value but I can't copy it since it's a formula. Is there a way to have it paste as raw text automatically ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not automatically but you can copy then paste as values.

Comment: So there is no way to just find raw text from a cell and copy / paste it without using ctrl shift v?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way of doing it using the script editor.

If anyone want to have the answer :

```
function onEdit(e){
  var copyFromRange = 'sheetX!U7';
  var copyToRangeStart = 'sheetX!U8';
  copyValuesOnly(copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart);
}

function copyValuesOnly(copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange(copyFromRange);
  source.copyTo(ss.getRange(copyToRangeStart), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

You can also use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)).

### Code

```
function copyValuesOnly(copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = ss.getRange(copyFromRange).getValues();
  ss.getRange(copyToRangeStart).setValues(values)
}
```

### Extra

If you describe a bit about your scenario and what you are trying to achieve, I can offer you some help on how to do it in an optimal way. Looking at the code, two questions come to mind:

1. Do you need the values to be copied every time you edit anything in the spreadsheet?
2. Why do you need to have the values as strings, what are you going to do with them afterwards?